Untrusted self signed certificate even though I'm using letsencrypt/certbot on 22.04
My certificates are erroring out as untrusted self signed certificate even though I'm using letsencrypt/certbot on 22.04
https://decoder.link/sslchecker/mail.servicemouse.com/587

certbot is only dealing with the web server. If you want to reuse the certificate from the web server for your mail server (which port 587 obviously is) see https://serverfault.com/questions/1158354/postfix-not-updating-lets-encrypt-certificate

I saw the page, which is the significant sentence on the page?
